# Best time to ask a question

Tags: discussion, statistics

I wondered if anyone made any statistics on this.

When is the best time (usually) to ask a question?

(with this I mean that it maximises the views the answer receives).

I figure that most of the contributors of this site are in the US, so the best time to do that should be during daytime according to the US.

Maybe some sort of index like $\frac {\text{Active user}}{\text{Questions asked per second}} $ can be used..

Do you have any data on this?

Comment: One could look at the data at http://data.stackexchange.com and figure something out.

Comment: This might also depend on the topic you're asking, and the level of question/answer.

Comment: See also http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2133/number-of-answers-views-votes-depends-on-hour-of-posting

Comment: Another related question: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3865/depending-on-the-tag-is-there-a-possibility-to-know-on-which-days-and-hours-are

Comment: Best time is when you have the inspiration to write a great question.

Comment: As a master of procrastination, I must say that the best time is always later. Perhaps at some point I'll flesh that into an answer...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I suggest a better metrics: the probability of getting an answer.

These are graphs by a [small tool](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213603/question-and-answer-activity-on-stackexchange-interactive-and-customized-editio) I made to measure this probability:

### Probabilities of getting an answer on Mathematics.SE by time

*Please, refer to [the original post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213603/question-and-answer-activity-on-stackexchange-interactive-and-customized-editio) for how to read these graphs.*

### With-*day*

[image: With-day probabilities for Mathematics.SE]

### With-*week* probabilities for Mathematics.SE

[image: With-week probabilities for Mathematics.SE]

Comment: Is it as per GMT or your countrie's local time

Comment: @ManishKumarSingh I believe it is GMT. See the question Anton Tarasenko asked in stackexchange meta.

Answer (score 14):

There is no data available for anything like "users currently online". The request [Displaying Users Online](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22895/) has [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) (for  reasons that are better articulated in [View approximate number of users online](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2631/)). The philosophical reason is that SE is not for disposable quick questions; there are [other sites](https://answers.yahoo.com/dir/index?sid=396545161) for those. SE is for collecting reusable content of high quality.

The best time to ask a question is when

- You have identified a specific mathematical question you don't know an answer to.
- You have searched using the key terms in your question, without finding an answer.
- You have written a clear question, with [context, good title, appropriate tags and formatting, etc](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959/).

**Then** it's a good time to ask, regardless of what time is on your clock.

Comment: Hmm,.. it's rather idealistic approach not pragmatic...